# NPM5/Node8 Offline Package Installation

Tags: node.js, npm

What is the best way for offline installation of private module and external module like pm2 (Install globally)?

In npm2/node4 I was using the combination of bundle-deps and npm pack for my module and npmbox for pm2.

Comment: Can you give more specifications to 'best way'?

Comment: Best way means a working way :)